# "Target folder cannot be created" when trying to make Netbeans copy sources folder

Tags: php, apache, netbeans

I'm trying to test a php app I'm working on in my Netbeans environment, and so I'm setting it up to run on a local Apache server. It seems to work fine when I manually copy my project into the htdocs folder, but when I try to configure Netbeans to automatically copy the sources, It tells me "Target folder cannot be created". I've tried changing the folder from read-only, including everything mentioned [**here**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/cant-remove-read-only-attrubutes/18dbe910-4511-4794-80a0-f3f60251090a) but it doesn't seem to stick (Probably relevant to mention that I'm on Windows 7)

I could just keep manually copying it every time I want to test it, but that would be a major headache. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I had guessed, it was a Windows permissions issue. After doing pretty much the same thing over and over without the change sticking, it finally stuck, and I was able to get things working the way I wanted. Sigh...